# Bloomberg Laundry Day - count items in list, check socks for pairs, and organize all items alphabetically

Tags: java, testing

I'm trying to solve the following problem: https://codecon.bloomberg.com/challenger-series/33

> Input Specifications
>
> Each article of clothing will have its own separate line. You have a penchant for hoarding, so there is no guarantee as to the number of pieces, but you can assure yourself that each article can be easily categorized by description (name).
>
> Articles of clothing will be fed in as line-delimited list. See below for examples.
>
> Output Specifications
>
> Output should be an alphabetically (case-insensitive) sorted, line-delimited list of the articles of clothing along with their count. Each field (count, category) should be separated by a pipe (|). If you come across a sock without a soulmate, the count should be designated by a 0 (zero). Socks that are in pairs should be on separate lines from the socks of the same category without pairs, and should come before the pairless sock. See below for examples.
>
> Sample Input/Output
>
> INPUT

```
white shirt
polka dot sock
red sock
superhero shirt
torn jeans
polka dot sock
white shirt
polka dot sock
```

> OUTPUT

```
1|polka dot sock
0|polka dot sock
0|red sock
1|superhero shirt
1|torn jeans
2|white shirt
```

My attempt at a solution (https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/179931/bloomberg-laundry-day-count-items-in-list-check-socks-for-pairs-and-organize) is passing the sample test case (above) but failing secret test cases.

So, I'm wondering what extra information I should be extracting from the input and output specifications? For example, I'm storing my clothing and the associated counts in a TreeMap, but I first convert the clothing description into small caps, because I figure that a White Shirt is the same thing as a white shirt. But I've tried other things - I've tried (a) storing the original string and using CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER for my tree map, and (b) storing the original strings and the counts for those strings in a HashMap, and storing all unique original strings in an ArrayList, then sorting all the original strings by CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER at the end, then using this order to print the results. Each of these attempts succeeds on the sample test case and fails some secret test.

How can I write useful tests for this? I've tried the corner case of an empty input, and my program works as expected. What else can I look out for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example code:

```
String clothingItem = stdin.nextLine().toLowerCase();
incrementCount(clothingCount, clothingItem);
```

it looks like your storing the lowercase string, and not the original string. Question asks for original string, SORTED as if it were case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks! I thought I had tried this, but I tried again and it worked!